# Cannot connect to remote SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure

I have recently created a two VMs in azure.

- [Machine 1] is a database machine running SQL Server
- [Machine 2] runs a C# service that connects to the database

The machine running the service doesn't seem to be able to talk to the database. On service start I get a `SqlConnection` exception (below).

Things I've tried:

- SQL Server Management Studio on my development can talk to the database on [Machine 1]
- If I use the exact same connection parameters locally on my dev machine running from Visual Studio I can connect to the database [Machine 1]
- I installed SQL Server Management Studio onto [Machine 2] it can connect to the database on [Machine 1]
- [Machine 1] can ping [Machine 2]
- I have tried turning both the firewalls off for both machines

But still, the program running on [Machine 2] cannot connect to [Machine 1]

Here is my [redacted] connection string

```
<add name="XXXX" 
     connectionString="data source=XXXX;initial catalog=XXXX;
                       persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=XXXX;
                       multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                       application name=XXXX" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration

- Shared Memory = Enabled
- Named Pipes = Enabled
- TCP/IP = Enabled

This is the exception I get

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, System.Object, System.String, System.Security.SecureString, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.String, Boolean)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   SiloHost.SiloConfigurationFactory.OrleansTablesExists()    at
>   SiloHost.SiloConfigurationFactory.CreateOrleansTables()    at
>   SiloHost.SiloConfigurationFactory.CreateSqlConfiguration()    at
>   SiloHost.BifrostService..ctor()    at
>   SiloHost.Program+<>c.<Main>b__0_2(Topshelf.Runtime.HostSettings)    at
>   Topshelf.Builders.DelegateServiceBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Build(Topshelf.Runtime.HostSettings)
>
> Exception Info: Topshelf.ServiceBuilderException    at
>   Topshelf.Builders.DelegateServiceBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Build(Topshelf.Runtime.HostSettings)
>   at
>   Topshelf.Builders.RunBuilder.Build(Topshelf.Builders.ServiceBuilder)
>
>   at
>   Topshelf.HostFactory.New(System.Action`1)
>   at SiloHost.Program.Main()

I cannot replicate this on my local machine, but if I change my the IP of the database in my config to one that doesnt exist I get an identical looking error with a little more information:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: SQL server is configured to TCP/IP connections? Default, no.

Comment: My suspicion would be the permissions for your service user. Temporarily, if you run the service under a different user name (say, your user name), do you get the same exception ?

Comment: @BWA Good point, but yes its configured I think, Ill update the question in a second to reflect

Comment: Are you using the same credentials from the connection string to test the Sql Management Studio connection?

Comment: @Juan Yes its all identical IP / User / Password every time I try

Comment: @Subbu Its currently run under NETWORK_SERVICE, I tried local system too.  So I just tried it as the service account that I used to log in the machine as but that failed in the same way - how can I make MSSQL accepts connections from any account?

Comment: So just to double-check, when you connect with Sql Management Studio, you are using Sql Server Authentication, correct?

Comment: @Juan Yes, I have never connected to it via anything else

Comment: Can you post the top level error message? It looks like you trimmed it out of the stack. The human-readable one.

Comment: @Juan Unfortunately that's all I get because of where it failed [and the fact its built in release], I can replicate on my machine and posted the top level message at the bottom of my question

Comment: The error is telling you that the service cannot see the server. There are a number of things that can cause this. Have you checked the port number in the configuration? This may help figure out the problem: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

Comment: >>>If I replicate this error on my local machine (by changing the IP address to be one that doesnt exist) I get a little more information:...<<< So it's NOT the original error you get, right? To get THIS error you changed the IP to non existing one, so this is the error you get for wrong IP, but you pass in the right IP, so what is the original error you get?

Comment: @sepupic I posted the exact error I got, the only way I could replicate that error on a dev machine is by trying different things and by changing the database IP in my config I got the exact same callstack thrown.  Sure its not the identical error but helps convey that its a connection issue no?

Comment: I think you cannot substitute one error with another just because you are sure the cause is server not found. In the first case I have no idea what happens and in the second you pass wrong IP and it's obvious what error you will get. You could pass in wrong password and have another error, so why did you choose to pass in wrong IP?